# Why my app crash when I switch fragments fast?

Tags: android, runtime-error

My apps crash sometimes when I change the fragment with the navigationDrawer. 
The fatal error isn't helping much, How can I solve this problem? Thx

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: acr.acr_app, PID: 29425
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
   at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:359)
   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3656)
   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3751)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:492)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:200)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:196)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:192)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:188)
   at android.widget.TableRow.<init>(TableRow.java:61)
   at acr.acr_app.MyFragment3$2.onChildAdded(MyFragment3.java:170)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaer.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagp.zzSu(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzags$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
```

**Fragment3 line170: onStart() listener**

```
  tableRow = new TableRow(getContext());
  tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
  TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
  TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
```

Comment: try change getContext() = this and rebuild project

Comment: your getContext is becoming returning null.

Comment: Thx for the help, but i can't use "this" inside my fragment, that's why i used getContext(). Is there another solution using onAttach/onDetach method?

Comment: Instead of "this" you can use "YourFragmentName.this". However this probably won't solve your issue. Check my answer below for a possible solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this crash is that the fragment is still executing code while it is already detached from your Activity.

In your case the Fragment is already switched to another Fragment when it reaches the `getContext()`. Because `getContext()` is looking for the Activity (which the fragment is no longer attached to) it will cause a nullpointer exception.

Try the following:

```
 if(isAdded()){
    tableRow = new TableRow(getContext());
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
 }
```

Comment: This worked fine! It's not crashing anymore but I need more testing to be sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is your fragment's working mode of `fragmentManager`? Is it `:replace` or `showhide`?  It will crash if you switch fast, because your fragment has not completed initialization when it attaches to `FragmentActivity`. Try something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I fixed it. It was because I was using `requireView()` and `requireContext()` everywhere. When we try to move from one fragment to other fast, as the `onViewCreated()` is half way through, the `requireView()` and `requireContext()` will not be able to get the view or context, thus it will throw an error and the app will crash. To prevent that, save the view and context in a variable at the beginning and reuse that variable.

Example:

```
private lateinit var myContext : Context
```

and inside onViewCreated() add:

```
myContext = getContext()
```

then reuse the variable:

```
if(isAdded()){
tableRow = new TableRow(myContext);
tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
```

}